# Creating Visual Studio templates under the "Windows" category.

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I have created a template for Visual Studio 2008 and it currently shows up under File->New Project->Visual C#. However, it is only really specific to Visual C#/Windows but I can't work out how to get it to show up under the "Windows" category and not the more general "Visual C#".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out MSDN "[How to: Locate and Organize Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx)"

Create a folder within one of these

```
<VisualStudioInstallDir>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\
My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\
```

Answer (score 0):

Categorization of templates depends on settings (for example, if you choose "C#" settings, all of a sudden all other languages move to an "other languages" tree).

What folder is your template in?